# basic http authentication with cms pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-authentication, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I am using rails 4 and comfortable mexican sofa.  I wish to secure some cms pages with password protection. They don't need to be very secure.  The following code gives me an undefined method error:

```
module CmsPagesAuth

  def authenticate
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret"
  end
end
```

the method is part of ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic
How to I get access to the method in question?  Or is there a better way I should be going about this problem?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions, solutions or insights.

Comment: you would have to do this in your controller

Comment: application_controller.rb?

Comment: yes if you want it to be applied for all the controllers. If not, add it to the specific controller

Comment: I see you read the wiki entry about this. Cool. But I think you want to use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic It's basically implementation of the default auth cms is using: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/authentication/http_auth.rb If you want to protect only certain pages just check for `@cms_path.full_path` before doing that basic auth.

Comment: @Grocery, thank you.  Your suggestion worked and I am on the right track.  My implementation of your suggestion seems to conflict with CMS admin Auth so I may have to use some other form of Auth anyways but your suggestion cleared some things up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: [your static actions]
end
```

Comment: thank you vimsha.  That worked.  However, all my cms pages seem to be controlled by:  CmsContentController#render_html so I am not sure how to exclude certain pages.  If I am not mistaken, CMS seems to de-emphasize the use of Controllers.